# PostgreSql + Searching Issue for "'" present in string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, mysql

Here, I have a problem in searching record in Postgresql DB in RoR Application. Name of table :: address_books, name of attributes ::  organization_name, federal_tax_id, city, zip , business_name. In search, organization name contain :: Claire's Inc as record. At the time of searching, it does not show the data while we select Claire's Inc in search box. Because "'" breaks the string and gives no result. So I have used "?" replace "'" at time of search in mysql and it works. But I am getting appropriate conversion to make search of this words.

```
Query :: SELECT * FROM "address_books" 
WHERE ( address_books.organization_name = 'Claire?s Inc' 
and address_books.federal_tax_id = '59-0940416' 
and address_books.city = 'Hoffman Estates' 
and address_books.zip = '60192' and address_books.business_name ='' ) 
ORDER BY address_books.organization_name , city LIMIT 100
```

Please suggest any other way to make successful search.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're messing up your data to deal with a matter of query syntax. Put a correctly escaped apostrophe in the place where the apostrophe should be.

One way is to escape it to `'Claire''s Inc'`. Another is to use a library that lets you pass parameters and handles the escaping for you. Another is to enter the string as `$$Claire's Inc$$` though that syntax allows for other things that may not be appropriate here.

Comment: Sorry, I not getting you. Please explain it briefly. Thanks

Comment: I'm saying, stop with the whole idea of replacing `'` with another character and just put in `'` where it should go. The syntax allows you to escape `'` so it won't break strings.

Comment: Take a read at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS because there's other variants of this that you really do need to know here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use RoR parameter substituion, than RoR will escape your dangerous strings for you. something like:

```
AddressBook.find(:all, :conditions => { "organization_name => ?", "Claire's Inc" })
```

or

```
AddressBook.find(:all, :conditions => { :organization_name => "Claire's Inc" })
```

Comment: Ya, I need sql injection prevention method but Your putting direct value infact you have to use params over here.

Comment: Well, i am actually using params here. ROR has several ways to define params for queries 1)via question mark 2)via :symbols. You can take a look here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html